# Laravel image file upload using blade templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello there i am facing a file uploading issue with Blade template engine and Laravel validation
Need some help from Laravel Experts check the image below for error. Thanks in Advance
Blade Code

```html
<h1>Create Post</h1>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store'], ['method' => 'POST', "enctype" => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}
    {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
    {{Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control'], ['placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
    {{Form::textarea('body', '',['class'=> 'form-control'],['placeholder' => 'Text here'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::file('cover_image')}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::submit('Post', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

store method is like this

```html
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'cover_image' => 'required|image|max:1999 '
            ]);
            //Handle file upload
            if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
                //get file name with extension
                $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
                //get just file name
                $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                //just file extension
                $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                //file name to store
                $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
                //image upload
                $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);

            }else{
                $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
            }
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $post->cover_image = $request->cover_image;
        $post->save([enter image description here][1]);
        return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post Created Successfully');
            
    }
```

The Error is it always says to upload an image file. see screenshot below.

Comment: What is the error? Please specify the error you faced.

Comment: Problem Solved,

Comment: The Problem was with this line {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store'], ['method' => 'POST', "enctype" => "multipart/form-data"]) !!}

Comment: every thing should be wrapped in one Bracket i separated them. the Solution is {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store' , "enctype" => "multipart/form-data", 'method' => 'POST', ]) !!}

Answer (score 1):

every thing should be wrapped in one Bracket i separated them. the Solution is

{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store' , "enctype" => "multipart/form-data", 'method' => 'POST', ]) !!}